# How to use both default export and normal exports in RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

**lib.js**

```
exports.value = 'Some value'

module.exports = {
  libraryName: '@CoolLibrary'
}
```

**main.js**

```
const { value } = require('./lib')
console.log('Value is '.concat(value))
```

When I write a code like above, see the output as `Value is undefined`. However, I have exported the `value` as `Some value` in the library.

Seems like I'm missing something.

What is the right way to export using both `module.exports` and `export.[value]` in Node.js?

Comment: Note: Node.js doesn't use [tag:requirejs], which is (primarily) a browser library. `require` is implemented by Node.js itself, see [the CJS module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exports` is an alias for `module.exports`, so when you do

```
module.exports = {
  libraryName: '@CoolLibrary'
}
```

you completely replace the object that you just assigned `value` to, making `value` unavailable.

This is one good reason not to *replace* the `exports` object; instead, just add to it:

```
exports.value = 'Some value';
exports.libraryName = '@CoolLibrary';
```

or if you like:

```
Object.assign(exports, {
    value: 'Some value',
    libraryName: '@CoolLibrary'
});
```